# copy a string into another C

Tags: c, string

in the K&R book the following is given as initial (and correct) function to copy a string

```
void strcpy (char *s, char *t)
{
    while ( (*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
        ;
}
```

Then it's said that an equivalent function would be

```
void strcpy (char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

I don't understand how the while loop can stop in the second case.

Thanks

Comment: Once the expression is equal to zero, it is equivalent to a logical "false". "True" otherwise.

Comment: Anyway, the second snippet is not very reader-friendly, as one can easily misinterpret the assignment operator with comparison, and  miss the point of the code.

Comment: Use a modern book or tutorial. This one does not even use the `const` qualifier.

Comment: @EugeneSh: Actually every halfway modern compiler should warn about the assignment.

Comment: @Eugene This is true in almost every programming language; I don't understand why  assigning to the address pointed by s the value pointed by t should give either 0 or 1 as result
Olaf could you please give references?

Comment: It shouldn't. It should give zero or non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple assignment expression has two effects:

1) stores the value to the lvalue on the left hand side (this is known as a 'side-effect')

2) the expression itself evaluates to a value - the value of what assigned to that lvalue

A `while` loop will repeat until its condition evaluates to 0. So the loop in the second example runs until the value 0 is assigned to the destination string.

Comment: perfect, this is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because for an expression, the result of the expression is returned.

```
if( (a = 4) == 4)
```

This `if` statement will evaluate to `True`.

---

So, in your case

```
while (*s++ = *t++)
```

when it reaches the `NUL` character `\0`, it will evaluate to `False`, and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `*s++ = *t++` has also a value after evaluation. If it evaluates to non zero value then condition is `true` otherwise `false`.

`while (*s++ = *t++)` is equivalent to `while ((*s++ = *t++) != 0)`.

Comment: This is because language writer decided that.

Comment: In C every expression returns a value unless it is a `void` function.